# Append Existing Columns to another Column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning, dataframe

I have a data that looks like this:
[image]
The T2M indicates the temperature, and the followed row is the year. I want to append all the similar parameters columns under a single column having all the years, I will end up with one T2M column only, and the final dataframe would look like this

```
Parameter | T2M  | ...
Year      | 1981 | ...    
Jan
Feb 
.
.
Year      | 1982 | ...
.
.
.
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
dff = df.copy()
temp = df.iloc[:,1]
dff.append(temp)
```

I get this error :

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

which doesn't make sense because [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) in the first example similar indices were used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem. The duplicate axis error was coming because the dataframe has multiple columns with the name 'T2M' so `append()` could not figure to which column it would append the new values.

Instead, I copied the dataframe, in the copy I deleted all columns to be appended, and extracted the data from the original df to the copied one. Since in the copy all columns are unique, everything went fine.